# Using a for loop to insert javascript variable into json encoded php variable

Tags: javascript, php, json

I've got several items I'm trying to display within a `canvas`.  I've `json` my `php` data to support doing this in `javascript`.

Now I'm trying to iterate the `database` names with a `for` loop so I don't have to write the code for each.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
for ((var i=2; i<=17; i++) && (var j=3; i<=18; j++)){

if((row.g1c[j]y + row.g1c[j]m != 0) && ((12*row.g1c[j]y + row.g1c[j]m) > (360 + (12*row.O1y + row.O1m)))){

    var g1c[i]w = (360-(12*row.g1c[i]y + row.g1c[i]m)-(12*row.O1y + row.O1m));

} else if (row.g1c[j]y +row.g1c[j]m != 0){

   var g1c[i]w = ((12*row.g1c[j]y + row.g1c[j]m)-(12*row.g1c[i]y + row.g1c[i]m));

} else {}

var g1c[i]x = ((12*row.g1c[i]y + row.g1c[i]m)-(12*row.O1y + row.O1m));
var lineHeight = 15;
var maxWidth = 2.5*(g1c[i]w);
var x = 80+(2.5*(g1c[i]x))+(maxWidth/2);

}
```

This isn't working and I'm 99.999% sure it has to do with the i and j syntax, but everything I've looked up and tried hasn't worked.

If someone would tell me where my screw-up is, I'd be eternally grateful.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `for ((var i=2; i<=17; i++) && (var j=3; i<=18; j++)){` This is not how you perform `for` loop.

Comment: Thanks Amit, then should I nest the loops?

Comment: Check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decided do go down the PHP route vice Javascript to avoid having to redo my database...

I'm creating a for loop for each database column and row...

```
for ($j=3; $j<=$count; $j++){
    $l = "g1c".$j."m";
    $m = "g1c".$j."y";
```

I can then use php logic as needed for each row of data that needs to be assessed...

```
if(($row[$l] + $row[$m]) != 0){
.... do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do this:

```
for (var i=2; i<=17; i++){
    for (var j=3; i<=18; j++){
        if((row.g1c[j]y + row.g1c[j]m != 0) && ((12*row.g1c[j]y + row.g1c[j]m) > (360 + (12*row.O1y + row.O1m)))){

            var g1c[i]w = (360-(12*row.g1c[i]y + row.g1c[i]m)-(12*row.O1y + row.O1m));

        } else if (row.g1c[j]y +row.g1c[j]m != 0){

        var g1c[i]w = ((12*row.g1c[j]y + row.g1c[j]m)-(12*row.g1c[i]y + row.g1c[i]m));

        } else {}

        var g1c[i]x = ((12*row.g1c[i]y + row.g1c[i]m)-(12*row.O1y + row.O1m));
        var lineHeight = 15;
        var maxWidth = 2.5*(g1c[i]w);
        var x = 80+(2.5*(g1c[i]x))+(maxWidth/2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Gave it a shot....still drawing a blank canvas....are my [i] and [j] syntax correct?

Comment: What is `y` and `m` here?

Comment: y is year and m is month.  they're just labels from my sql database.

Comment: my desired syntax after the row.g1c1m, then g1c2m, as the for loop iterates.

Comment: Why are you using them in JavaScript? Cause they are producing errors.

Comment: I'm with you on that....how do I resolve this since my database naming convention is already setup?